# Give all items infinite durability on startup in Minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i'm a user from Terraria, which has both no durability and no hunger (Hunger Strike fixed this). The only things i've seen to avail is for server creators in which case you can use a command for an individual item. I want something like a datapack or command to give all items in my inventory infinite durability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just the `Unbreakable` tag. But you can't modify player inventories, so you will have to instruct the player to throw items onto the ground and then run `/execute as @e[type=item] run data merge entity @s {Unbreakable:1}`.